# Searching multiple models with Searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, searchkick

I'm working on a Rails 5 and Searchkick project that has a search feature with filters that search multiple models. For example, I have College and State models that are joined. I'd like to be able to search the College model for a specific campus setting and search the State model for a specific state. I'd like the query to use an AND operator, instead of an OR, but so far, I can only find information on using an OR in previous Searchkick issues. Thus far, what I've come up with is:

```
@results = College.search "*", index_name: [College, State], where: {_and: [{_type: "college", campus_setting: 21}, {_type: "state", state: "Massachusetts"}]}
```

Ideally, I'll build a hash with all of the where conditions, for example:

```
where:{
  {_type: "college", campus_setting: 21},
  {_type: "state", state: "Massachusetts"}
}
```

And then pass the where conditions to the search:

```
@results = College.search "*", index_name: [College, State], where: [where]
```

But this doesn't return any results, even though I can directly query my database and get results.

In SQL, my query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM colleges c
INNER JOIN states s
ON c.state_id = s.id
WHERE c.campus_setting = 21 AND s.state = 'Massachusetts';
```

Is there another way I can write this search, or is this feature unavailable? The closest thing I can find is here: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/904

Answer (score 1):

Actually searchkick provides a facility to perform multi-model searches, take a look at the documentation here: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#multi-search

and the provided example:

```
fresh_products = Product.search("fresh", execute: false)
frozen_products = Product.search("frozen", execute: false)
Searchkick.multi_search([fresh_products, frozen_products])
```

If you use different models you can use:

```
fresh_products = Product.search("apples", execute: false)
frozen_products = FrozenProduct.search("ice", execute: false)
Searchkick.multi_search([fresh_products, frozen_products])
```

Also by [looking at the tests](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/master/test/multi_search_test.rb) you may be able to find some guidance.

Comment: Thanks for responding!  I'm using two different models, not from the same model.

Comment: @AndreaS see the updated answer... I thought you're be able to try it ;)

Comment: Multi_search is for batching search requests for performance and does not search both models at once.

Comment: @TenJack can you explain more what you mean "search requests for performance?" how does that work if theyre not async? my goal is to search across multiple models but have the results returned as instances of that class like searchkick does normally for a standard Thing.search(...), but I also want it to be performant

Answer (score 1):

```
Searchkick.search "mike", models: [Video, Image]
```

Search with more advanced options -

```
Searchkick.search "mike", { fields: ["slug^5", "title", "about"], misspellings: {below: 5, edit_distance: 2}, models: [Video, Image]}
```

Comment: How to add model specific fields?

Comment: The fields key can contain any attribute of any model, which is indexed in ElasticSearch, you can try adding and see to it yourself.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. It did work

Comment: what if I have 2 fields named "name" and I want to treat them differently as far as boosting?

Comment: keys must be different if you want different treatment else it would be treated just like single name field and the search parameter that you are looking for including boosting.

Comment: @red-devil, there is no such thing as "model specific " fields in elastic search, it will search everything unless you specify which model/document to search and which fields.
Check this link for Searchkick Github page - https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#querying